# How to create a Random Generator for Movie Clip MouseEvents?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, random, mouseevent

I am currently working on a game to where there are different `MovieClip` objects that are added to the stage by a timer event array.

These movie clips are handled by the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`, so when ever the user touches the correct object that is displayed on the screen, then the `nScore` adds 1 point but what I wanted to do was after a random amount of time or a random amount of points that the user gets I want one of the objects to no longer be active so if you touch the object that is not active then the user loses. Then after a random time or score the object changes again and you have to only touch that object and not the previous one displayed on the screen etc...

So I created two mouse event listeners like so:

```
mSquare.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, SquareNotActivated);
mSquare.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, SquareIsActivated);
```

so in my SquareIsActivated function I have another function called `SquareActivate` which has the following code:

```
private function SquareActivate(square:DisplayObject):void 
{          
    nScore ++;
    updateHighScore();
    updateCurrentScore();          
}
```

In my SquareNotActivated function its the same thing i have a function called`squareNotActive` which has the following code:

```
private function squareNotActive(square:DisplayObject):void 
{  
     nLives --;
}
```

Then for another Movie Clip object called `mPop`I have the same setup.

I was going to try and make multiple `if` statements for the `nScore` to handle the change of event listeners as well as the display object i was going to try and do it like this:

```
private function checkNScore():void 
{
    if (nScore >= 2)
    {
        // then remove a mouse listener for one object and add another
        stage.addChild(pop_Icon);
        pop_Icon.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + 180;
        pop_Icon.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - 300;             

    }

    if (nScore >= 4)
    {    
        //Remove Square icon
        pop_Icon.destroyPopIcon();

        //Add new Square icon
        stage.addChild(square_Icon);
        square_Icon.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + 180;
        square_Icon.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - 300;
    }
}
```

But I know there has to be a way to call them randomly maybe a timer object that generates a random `MovieClip` that the user has to touch then putting all other movie clips to remove a life instead of multiple `if` statements. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to extends `MovieClip` to create an other class for you clickable objects ant add a `type` property to them.

On a timer event you just change the target type.

In this way, you could use just the same function for all your objects.

## *Ex:*

### *the extended MovieClip class:*

```
package test
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    /**
     * This is a class that extends MovieClip and have a public type property.
     */
    public class MyObject extends MovieClip
    {
        public var type :int;

        public function MyObject( type = 0 )
        {
            super();
            this.type = type;

            // for this test i just create a circle with a color associated with the type
            this.graphics.beginFill( type*50 );
            this.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,20);
            this.graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

### *how to use:*

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    import test.MyObject;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        /** the timer to change the type **/
        private var timer       :Timer;
        /** the current target type **/
        private var targetType  :int;
        /** the objects available **/
        private var objects     :Vector.<MyObject>;

        /** the last time of the enterFrameEvent **/
        private var lastTime        :int;
        /** the last time the target type changed **/
        private var lastTypeChanged :int;
        /** the last time we created an object **/
        private var lastObjectCreated   :int;

        public function Main()
        {
            objects = new Vector.<MyObject>();

            generateObject();
            changeTargetType();

            lastTime = getTimer();
            addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );
        }

        /** generate a new object and place it on the stage **/
        private function generateObject():void
        {
            // generate a random type
            var type:int = int(Math.random()*10)
            // create the object
            var o:MyObject = new MyObject( type );
            // place the object randomly on the stage
            o.x = 50 + (Math.random() * 350);
            o.y = 50 + (Math.random() * 350);
            // add mouse evtn listener to the object
            o.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick );
            // add the object to the display list
            addChild( o );
            // add the object to the array
            objects.push( o );
            // reset the timer
            lastObjectCreated = 0;
        }

        private function changeTargetType():void
        {
            // get an object randomly on the array to be sure the type is available on screen
            var typeId:int = Math.random()*objects.length;
            // get the type of the random object
            targetType = objects[typeId].type;
            // reset the timer
            lastTypeChanged = 0;

            trace( "new Type::",targetType );
        }

        /** on enter frame, calculate the passed time and see what you want to do **/
        private function onEnterFrame( event:Event ):void
        {
            // calculate passed time
            var passedTime:int = getTimer() - lastTime;
            //trace( passedTime, lastTime, lastTypeChanged, lastObjectCreated );
            lastTime = getTimer();
            // add the time to the timers
            lastTypeChanged += passedTime;
            lastObjectCreated += passedTime;

            // create an object each 5 seconds
            if( lastObjectCreated >= 5000 )     generateObject();
            // change the target type each 10 seconds
            if( lastTypeChanged >= 10000 )      changeTargetType();
        }

        /** handle the click **/
        private function handleClick( event:MouseEvent ):void
        {
            // get the object clicked
            var o:MyObject = event.target as MyObject;

            // if it is the goo type
            if( o.type == targetType )
            {
                //update the score
                trace( "yeah" );
                //--> do what you want

                //remove the object from the displayList
                removeChild(o);
                // remove listeners on the object
                o.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick );
                // remove the object from the array
                var i:int = objects.indexOf(o);
                objects.splice(i,1);
            }
            else
            {
                // remove life.
                trace( "bad" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this could help you :)